# What is the best way to parse chunked-encoded http response in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm

I have to use custom method name `STATS`, which is not supported by nodejs http module.

So, i decided to use tcp socket:

```
feed.socket = net.createConnection(config.port, config.host);
feed.socket.on('connect', function() {
  feed.socket.write(
    'STATS / HTTP/1.1\r\n' + 
    'Authorization: Basic ' + new Buffer(config.user + ':' + config.password).toString('base64') + '\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: custom-http-client/0.0.1\r\n' + 
    'Host: ' + config.host + '\r\n' +
    'Accept: */*\r\n\r\n'
  );
});

feed.socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```

After i perform connection, server sends headers & then starts to send chunks of data via persistent connection:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 13:23:54 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Capability: streamlist stats

1fcf // data size
...DATA...
```

I can detect and ignore headers, i can concatenate string lines from different chunks, but it's very complex to handle data sizes manually, that are sent in chunks.

Perhaps there is a solution, that could handle headers, chunked-encoded data and return line-by-line data?

Comment: What do you mean, not supported by the http module? node.js doesn't care what you call your HTTP method. It just won't have any specific behavior for your custom method.